# How to connect nginx to local mongodb

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, nginx

I've got nginx to run my (node.js/react) application on the server. But I can't seem to connect to the database.

In the nginx.conf file I've added the following inside http.

```
http {
    ...
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
    ...}
...}
```

And above the http section I have the following,

```
stream {
    server {
        listen  4000;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1s;
        proxy_timeout 3s;
        proxy_pass    stream_mongo_backend;
    }

    upstream stream_mongo_backend {
      server 127.0.0.1:27017;
  }
}
```

I start the nginx server, the application runs on localhost, opens up the login page but I can't login because it's still not connected to the database (mongodb). 
I'm not sure if I've got my port numbers wrong or if I'm missing some configuration line inside nginx.conf.

EDIT: Ok, I had it wrong before. I wasn't supposed to connect to mongodb at this point. I was supposed to connect to the backend server of my application which would run at 4000. So now I've added a new location for /api/ inside http and proxied all requests to 4000. I still have one question though. I have to run my backend server separately for this to work. For the frontend I've created a folder and put all my build files in there so nginx starts up the webserver from there. Doing the same for the backend did not start up the server. Is there a way to get nginx to start the backend server as well? 
Also can I get the frontend to run directly without the build files ? Like node would with npm start?

Answer (score 0):

the port number is right. try to open up a `mongo` shell and see if you are able to access a `mongo` instance. if not, you will need to run `sudo service mongodb start` to start it up.

Comment: I do have mongod running. I'm also able to view the dbs and collections after running mongo.  
I'm not entirely sure of the port number 4000 in the stream section. When I run my client from npm start I have the server running at 4000 which is why I used that number. 
Also this is on windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Guess it's knida late but you don't need to setup nginx for your backend to connect local mongodb.

And you need to run the frontend and backend server first by `yarn start`, `node run` or something like that if you want to run it without build files.

And then bypass the calls from 80 port to the local host servers.
For example, your FE run at 3000 port, BE run at 5000 port.
Then your nginx should be:

```
http {
...
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /api/ {
       proxy_pass localhost:5000;
     }

    location / {
        proxy_pass localhost:3000;
     }
...}
...}
```